# Accessing response data using Angular.js with numerical named field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My response object has a field called "50", so right now I'm trying to access and save that data doing something like this:

`var thing = $scope.data.array[0].50;`

However I'm getting an error on the console when I simply reload the page with the function not even running. When I get rid of the 50, everything is fine. There is indeed a field called "50" inside the `$scope.data.array[0]` and I do not have access to change the response. Is there something wrong with this because the field is called "50" and maybe JS is interrupting that as a number instead??

Also when I changed "50" to something random like "af", then I get no errors on refresh.

this doesn't work
`var thing = $scope.data.array[0].50;`

this works 
`var thing = $scope.data.array[0].af;`

Comment: Try `var thing = $scope.data.array[0]["50"];`

Comment: @JoshC Cool thx! that works!

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/javascript-object-property-name-as-number

Comment: That is a terrible name for a field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work if your first element of the array has a property called "50".

`var thing = $scope.data.array[0]["50"];`

Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.

```
Syntax
object.property
object["property"]
```

JavaScript objects are also associative arrays (hashes). Using these you can associate a key string with a value string as shown in the example above.

The reason as to why you don't get an error when accessing `$scope.data.array[0].af;` is because "af" is valid identifier for a property. Dot notation only works with property names that are valid identifiers. An identifier must start with a `letter`, `$`, `_` or `unicode escape sequence`.

For all other property names, you must use bracket notation.

Comment: @Yan Please make sure to accept the answer if it solved your problem.