# What's the benefit of using numbers as properties in a javascript object initialization?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and after reading a tutorial on how to initialize an object, I found the following example:

```
var obj = {  property_1: value_1,   // property_# may be an identifier...
                      2: value_2,   // or a number...
                                    // ...,
           "property n": value_n }; // or a string
```

My doubt is in the property with a number as a name. I understand this, but I can't find a real benefice of using it. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/javascript-object-property-name-as-number) and, from my point of view, this kind of notation could lead to bad design or an unnecessary complexity in my code, so I would like to know why this syntax exist.

Do this kind of declaration is used frequently? In what kind of scenarios this could be an ideal alternative?

Comment: There is no particular benefit. It looks like the code was written that way simply to demonstrate different valid property names in an object literal.

Comment: That's terrible code that's typically written by people who don't know what arrays are. Run from it like fire. Sadly it's used pretty frequently.

Comment: Its usefull in any scenario where you would need a HashMap functionality with ID's as keys

Comment: @xjedam if you want a map use a `Map`.

Comment: @Benjamin Map is not fully supported in all browsers I think

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you could use an _Object_ as the `iterable` in `new Map(iterable)`

Comment: @PaulS.: Objects are not iterable (by default), they're only enumerable. You'd need `new Map(Reflect.enumerate(obj))`

Comment: @Bergi The following will work in _Google Chrome_ (though it's _very very_ unlikely you'd ever write something like it in practice) `new Map(Object.assign(Object.create(Array.prototype), {0: ['foo', 'bar'], length: 1}))`, i.e. this is an _Object_, `new Map` is accepting it

Comment: @PaulS.: He, an object that inherits `Symbol.iterator` from `Array.prototype` can hardly be called "default" :-) Of course even `[]` is an object as well, but that's not what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Arrays

JavaScript arrays are objects where some of the keys are integers(*).

`[9, 8, 7]` is similar to an object `{ 0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 7 }`.

The main difference is that the array has a prototype of [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) instead of [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

(*) As Benjamin Gruenbaum points out, the array keys are coercible to UInt32. Keys of objects are always either strings or symbols. And as djechlin points out, arrays are allowed to have properties with any kind of key, but I do not recommend adding your own non-integer keys on an array.

## Arguments

An array-like object called `arguments` is available within any function (*). Each argument received by the function will be a property on `arguments`, with an integer-like key.

In the following code, the `example` call returns an object like `{ 0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 7, length: 3 }`.

```
function example(a, b, c) {
    return arguments;
}
example(9, 8, 7);
```

(*) [In modern JavaScript, there is no `arguments` object in arrow functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments)

Comment: *Where the keys are coercible to UInt32. The keys of objects are always either strings or symbols.

Comment: `var foo = []; foo.chicken = 'chicken'` - keys are not necessarily integers.

Comment: And `length` is of course a property with key `length`, which is not an integer.

Comment: I would say the main difference between `[9,8,7]` and `{0: 9, 1:8, 2:7}` is that the former is an `Array`. it has methods such as `map` for instance that the object does not.

Comment: @djechlin I see your non-integer property name _length_ and raise you a _splice_ to make it pretty in the console

Comment: `var foo = []; foo[-3] = 2;` is an array with highest integer index `-3` but its length is 0, not -2.

Comment: While all these comments are true, you _can_ use non.integer keys in an array, using integer keys in an object feels somehow OK whereas using string keys in an array really doesn't.  Given that assumptions are often made (when looping for example) for arrays based on the value of the `length` property, I be happy to use an object with only integer keys but would rrecommend against abusing arrays in this fashion.

Comment: `var foo = []; foo[100000000000000]= 3;` gives `foo.length` as 0, not 100000000000001.

Comment: `var foo = []; foo.length = 12;` gives length as 12, not 0.

Comment: @djechlin Okay, I guess I won't try to summarize the behavior of `length` here, since it's not relevant enough to be worthwhile.

Comment: yeah a bit but pretty much everything in your answer is inaccurate. I would have been happy with "Arrays are examples of objects that use numbers as keys" but the rest of your explanation is problematic. Arrays are indeed a good example of objects that use numbers as keys but then you describe the difference between arrays and objects -- inaccurately, and exclude arraylike objects (such as `arguments`) in the process.

Comment: `arguments` is probably the best example of a non-array object that uses integer-like keys. Yes, I should add that example too.

Comment: @djechlin There is a difference between _Arrays_ and _Objects_? _Arrays_ are a subset of the set of all _Objects_.

Comment: @PaulS. yes, I mentioned that "arrays are examples of objects" twice in my last comment. If you're concerned with, if something is a subset of something else, is there a difference between those two things, that's purely semantic.

Comment: well, arrays keys are actually strings, just to throw a wrench into yall's petty argument... the main diff between arrays and objects is the auto-computed length property and the prototype methods. arrays can be sparse, and at least in V8, it's not wasteful to use sparse arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Using integers as object keys is useful when creating sparse arrays and matrices, for instance mapping a 1000 element vector with 0 everywhere except the 10th element as

```
v = {10: 1}
```

JS arrays cannot be used here since you need to be able to specify the element position using the key.

In ECMAscript 6 using `[Map]`[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is better since it is actually made to be a mapping, but in codebases based on older ES standards, you would probably still see object being used for mappings like these.

Comment: Well you can use sparse arrays as well, but I guess you meant for serialisation, right? `[,,,,,,,,,1]` is not super sexy

Comment: I was more thinking of if you wanted to implement a sparse matrix multiplication function for instance. If you use a sparse array and multiply each element by 3 it will still attempt to perform the multiplication on unassigned elements.

Comment: Well that would be one of the few cases where you could use a `for in` loop on an array as well (or `Object.keys`, for that matter), if sparse iteration is what you are looking for. But yes, the difference between a sparse array and an integer-keyed object is negligible

Answer (score 0):

That code is contrived to make the point.  But, since you asked for an example where it could be used, let me give you a couple.

- It can happen that if you receive JSON formatted data it will be like
  this. Depends on details of the external system.
- Another might be for consistency.  E.g. suppose you had a data model
  from which you would generate your HTML.  It might be that is uses
  objects for the possible values for each field (assuming the field
  can only take one of a number of possible values).  These fields
  could then be rendered as radio buttons or as a select.  Some of
  these fields will use strings as possible values, so the natural
  thing is tyo make the possible values list into an object.  But some
  will use integer keys - still probably better to stick to the list
  always being an object.

E.g.

```
var prio_field_pos_vals = {
  0: 'Show Stopper',
  1: 'Urgent',
  2: 'High',
  3: 'Low' 
}
```

Of course, this would probably not be defined as a standalone variable but as part of a model, but you get the idea.  I would avoid integer keys (and keys with spaces in the string) for objects unless you have a reason for them, but when you have a reason, use them.

Comment: Of course JSON will always have quotes around keys, so rather `{"0":"…", …}`

Comment: On unordered object might not be the best fit for a list of radio buttons. An array of `{value: …, text: …, …}` records might be a better idea

Comment: Yes, if it came as JSON data (most liekly) it would have quotes.  Depends on how it is generated though.  Both valid in javascript as far as I am aware.