# javascript object property name as decimal notation

Tags: javascript

This is a more specific to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/javascript-object-property-name-as-number), which only goes as far as discussing keys as numeric whole integers.

In regards to 'numeric or string literal for the name of a property', I've tried this in the Chrome console

`var obj = { 2.15: 'foo' }
console.log(obj[2.15])`

and it works. I would not assume it standard across all browsers, especially older ones. However such a key notation as part of a default configuration provided by my users could be useful. I think using `Map`, though within standards (['Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)), could be intimidating. If it works, why should it not be used?

Comment: Both lines implicitly convert the number to a string. `typeof Object.keys(obj)[0] === "string"`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You can access it using obj["2.15"], it's supposed to be supported by all browsers

Comment: @torazaburo Do you know where I might find the official specification to whether or not I can use decimal fraction?

Comment: @Vivick I know I can use the string form, but it looks awkward

Comment: Using a floating point was a bit weird but if it's correct according to the specification then go ahead, less "number to string" conversion is always nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) says:

> ```
> PropertyName :
>   IdentifierName
>   StringLiteral
>   NumericLiteral
> ```

and shows that [floats are fine](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) in a *NumericLiteral*.

It's standard. Use it if you want to.