# Angular access ngFor index on another ngFor inside array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor

I have the following object:

```
itemList = {
    "0": [],
    "1": [],
    "2": [],
    "3": []
};
```

I also have the following `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let new of news; let newindex = index;">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList.newindex">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm trying to access `itemList[0]`, for example using the `newindex` created.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object property name as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/object-property-name-as-number)

Comment: use `$index` instead of index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `[]` notation to access property

```
<div *ngFor="let new of news; let newindex = index;">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList[newindex]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Your object is more like to array, so consider to make it as array, not an object with numeric property names.

Check [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3u6dj)

Comment: Not working, note that i have an object (itemList), and i'm printing the object and it has values on the arrays...

Comment: Have you checked the example ?

Comment: Yes, and replicated like that. Note that I'm updating itemList values dinamically, does it have something to do with the problem?

Comment: So it was basically an error of mine, i was missing an "x" on "index"... But i was missing the "[ ]" so thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the square brackets to get the value of `itemList` on that parent index `newindex`

```
<div *ngFor="let new of news; let newindex = index;">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList[newindex]">
  </div>
</div>
```