# Angular Interpolation of property name starting with digit

Tags: angular

I am using the following interpolation in Angular 4:

```
{{variable.24h_volume}}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Unexpected token '0.24' at column 5 in [{{variable.24h_volume}}] in ng:///AppModule/Component.html
```

What is the problem here?

Is it the property name starting with the digit?

Comment: Yes, it is the property name starting with the digit. Variables and property names cannot begin with numbers.

Comment: If you want to reference a property name starting with a digit or ones the property name is a digit , try ``{{variable['24h_volume']}}``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following my comment, I'm putting this as an answer if it can help other people.

To reference a property name starting with a digit or ones the property name is a digit , we can access that property using:

```
{{variable['24h_volume']}}
```

For more on that, please look at similar answers from SO questions like:

[accessing Object property name as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/object-property-name-as-number)

[What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835169/angular-interpolation-of-property-name-starting-with-digit/49835827#49835827)