# Javascript Object - Accessing values When Properties have special characters

Tags: javascript

I've following object and I need to access

```
let tempID= options._baseid; 

options->_metadata->98bb74e9-b168-4b83-8019-306af8fed977->name
```

However I'm unable to access this and value is always undefined.

This is my object:

[image]

This is the the javascript data variable. Same as the screenshot.

```
{
  "_parent": null,
  "_metadata": {
    "sTID": null,
    "sID": null,
    "iType": null,
    "lIDList": null,
    "lEList": null,
    "SfS": null,
    "sSrcID": null,
    "sSrcType": null,
    "98bb74e9-b168-4b83-8019-306af8fed977": {
      "id": "98bb74e9-b168-4b83-8019-306af8fed977",
      "type": 2,
      "name": "newTemplate0508"
    }
  },
  "_baseid": "98bb74e9-b168-4b83-8019-306af8fed977",
  "_sourcetype": "2"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object properties containing special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters) and [Object property name as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476)

Comment: Welcome! `options["_metadata"]["98bb74e9-b168-4b83-8019-306af8fed977"]["name"]`

Comment: I tried with bracket notation too but still value is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

try to access as following

```
yourObj._metadata[yourObj._baseid].name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the bracket notation instead of dot.

```
let tempID = options['_baseid']; 
options['_metadata']['98bb74e9-b168-4b83-8019-306af8fed977']['name']
```

Comment: i used Bracket notation too.. But still value is undefined.

Comment: Please post the Data variable in here instead of screenshot

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sharan_zweck/z543fg9q/

Check this

@TechProgrammer