# Binding Database Id to input field names

Tags: javascript, angular, database, database-design

I found out binding input fields name to integer values are not a good practice, but I don't know how else I can do this.

I have to generate dynamic input fields to submit user's medical test results. To associate these inputs with the test ids, I have put the key of the inputs as the ids of the test table.

my current database design

Test Data

```
| id | test_id | test_data |
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  | 1       | aaa       |
| 2  | 1       | bbb       |
```

Test Results

```
| id | client_test_id | test_data_id | result |
|----|----------------|--------------|--------|
| 1  | 1              | 1            | 120    |
| 2  | 1              | 2            | 230    |
```

How I currently generate my Input fields to submit Test results

In component

```
getTestData(testDatas: any) {
    this.clientTestDataNew = [];
    testDatas.forEach(testData => {
        let testDataItem = new TextTestDataItem({
            key: testData.id,
            label: testData.name,
            type: 'text',
            value: '',
            required: true,
            order: 1
        });
        this.clientTestDataNew.push(testDataItem);
    });
}
```

In Template

```
<form *ngIf="clientTestDataNew?.length > 0" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let clientTestDataItem of clientTestDataNew" class="form-row">
        <div [formGroup]="form">
            <label [attr.for]="clientTestDataItem.key">{{clientTestDataItem.label}}</label>
            <div [ngSwitch]="clientTestDataItem.controlType">
                <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="clientTestDataItem.key"
                    [id]="clientTestDataItem.key" [type]="clientTestDataItem.type">
                <select [id]="clientTestDataItem.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"
                    [formControlName]="clientTestDataItem.key">
                    <option *ngFor="let opt of clientTestDataItem.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{clientTestDataItem.label}} is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: hi @camille, are you getting any error by using integer value in 'formControlName'? or what?

Comment: No.. I don't get any errors. I want to know why this is a bad practice? and in my situation is there any work around

Comment: read this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/object-property-name-as-number if it can be helpful