# Import config with number as name

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm building a Discord bot (.js V12). I am now building a color command. Usage: `$color idhere`. The problem that I just encountered, is that I build my list like this:

```
exports.coloridlist = {
    1: "white",
    2: "grey",
    3: "etc",
}
```

When I try to import a value, it gives me an error, because of the numbers. Sample of my code:

```
    if (coloridlist.1 == args[0]) { // Problem here, coloridlist.1
      console.log(`${message.author.username} now has a new role color: ${args[0]}.`)
      .get(user.id)
      .roles.add(whiteTeamRole);
      message.channel.send(`You now have new rolecolor: <@roleidhere>.`)
    } else if (coloridlist.2 == args[0]) { // Problem here
      console.log(`${message.author.username} now has a new role color: ${args[0]}.`)
      .get(user.id)
      .roles.add(greyTeamRole);
      message.channel.send(`You now have new rolecolor: <@roleidhere>.`)
    } else if //etc
```

It would be easy for the user to just do `$color 1` (where `1` is the color id), since the string is vulnerable for type errors, and just not quick.

So does anyone know how I can work around this? Since I am working with 200+ colors with this sytem, it would be nice if I can fix this.

Comment: Use brackets instead. `coloridlist["1"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object property name as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/object-property-name-as-number)