# Number Error: identifier expected when module exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to import values of numbers from 1 to 20 to another js file [Index.js]
here's my current code:

```
const what = {};

what. 1 = { number: 1 };
what. 2 = { number: 2};
what. 3 = { number: 3}

module.exports = what;
```

I have an error of: `identifier expected` is there a way to fix this error? so I can import the values to my other script? please let me know :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object property name as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/object-property-name-as-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code like this:

```
module.exports = {
    1: { number: 1 },
    2: { number: 2 },
    3: { number: 3 },
};
```

You should then be able to access the properties with:

```
const obj = require('./path/to/file');
console.log(obj[1].number);
```