# Google scripts: Trying to push object into array. Logging works, Pushing works, but not both

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function pushGear(id) {
    var etroData = getResponse(`https://etro.gg/api/gearsets/${id}`);
    var bisGear = [
      [etroData.jobAbbrev],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.weapon).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.offhand).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.head).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.body).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.hands).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.legs).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.feet).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.ears).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.neck).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.wrists).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.fingerL).toFixed(0)],
      [Number.parseFloat(etroData.fingerR).toFixed(0)]
      ];
      Logger.log(etroData.materia);
    bisGear.forEach((gear, gearIndex) => {
      if(etroData.materia.hasOwnProperty(gear[0])) {
        for (const property in etroData.materia[gear]) {
          Logger.log(Number.parseFloat(etroData.materia[gear][property]).toFixed(0));
          bisGear[gearIndex].push('test');
          Logger.log(bisGear[gearIndex]);
        }
      };
      if(uniqueItems.indexOf(gear) == -1 && !isNaN(gear)){uniqueItems.push(gear)};
    });
    Logger.log(bisGear);
    return bisGear;
}
```

I seem to be able to do `bisGear[gearIndex].push('test')`, or the log `Logger.log(Number.parseFloat(etroData.materia[gear][property]).toFixed(0));` above it but when I try to do both, it seems to give this error

```
10:28:36 AM Error TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
(anonymous) @ GearPlanner.gs:52
pushGear    @ GearPlanner.gs:49
(anonymous) @ GearPlanner.gs:91
getGearset  @ GearPlanner.gs:91
```

I should be able to do both as they don't seem to be interacting with each other. Any ideas?

This is an example response from etro.gg API. I've removed some of the unused properties as stackoverflow was complaining that the post was mostly code.

```
{
    ...,
    "materia": {
    "35190": {
        "1": 33933,
        "2": 33933
    },
    "35192": {
        "1": 33933,
        "2": 33934
    },
    "35193": {
        "1": 33932,
        "2": 33932
    },
    "35194": {
        "1": 33933,
        "2": 33933
    },
    "35230": {
        "1": 33932,
        "2": 33933
    },
    "35235": {
        "1": 33932,
        "2": 33934
    },
    "35247": {
        "1": 33933,
        "2": 33933
    },
    "35265": {
        "1": 33932,
        "2": 33932
    },
    "35266": {
        "1": 33933,
        "2": 33933
    },
    "35269": {
        "1": 33933,
        "2": 33933
    },
    "35300": {
        "1": 33933,
        "2": 33934
    },
    "35090R": {
        "1": 33932,
        "2": 33934,
        "3": 33921,
        "4": 33921,
        "5": 33921
    },
    "35315L": {
        "1": 33933,
        "2": 33934
    },
    "36788R": {
        "1": 33932,
        "2": 33941
    }
},
    ...,
    "weapon": 35247,
    "head": 35190,
    "body": 35266,
    "hands": 35192,
    "legs": 35193,
    "feet": 35269,
    "offHand": null,
    "ears": 35300,
    "neck": 35230,
    "wrists": 35235,
    "fingerL": 35315,
    "fingerR": 36788,
    "food": 545,
    "medicine": null
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you could share a portion of the etro.gg/api/gearset response we could assist you in debugging your script.

Answer (score 0):

Array `bigGear` is an array of arrays of numbers.  You should leave them as strings.  You translate to a number.  Now in `Number.parseFloat(etroData.materia[gear][property]` gear is a number 35190 or the 35190 row of an array but needs to be a string "35190".

See this article [Object property name as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908476/object-property-name-as-number)